# Pandas: concat dataframe with multi-index dataframe. Whats wrong?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to concat two dataframes, df y df_multindex:

df:

```
COL1   COL2    COL1   COL2
 10     a       20     a
 21     w2      21     w2
```

df_multindex:

```
  0      0     1      1
COL1   COL2   COL1   COL2
  1     a       1     a
 21     w2     21     w2
```

1. df_multinidex has to be concat below df.
2. df_multinidex has to remain their column name levels.
3. So the column names of the new dataframe has to be the multindex names from df_multindex

What I have tried:

```
 dftotal = pd.concat([df,df_multindex], axis = 0)
```

What i got was:

```
 TypeError: Expected tuple, got str
```

What I want is:

```
   0      0     1      1
COL1   COL2   COL1   COL2
 10     a      20     a
 21     w2     21     w2
  1     a       1     a
 21     w2     21     w2
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need  `MultiIndex`  in both `DataFrames`, so use:

```
df.columns = df_multindex.columns

dftotal = pd.concat([df,df_multindex])
```